# Как можно написать словарь, вложенный в словарь, вложенный в словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в данном случае можно написать словарь, вложенный в словарь, вложенный в словарь? Что-то вроде такого

```
ready_for_nodes[nodes] = vm_to_create[new_vm_name]
```

```
response = requests.get('http://127.1.0.1/asl_real.json')
asl_vms = json.loads(response.text)
ready_nodes = {}
vm_to_create = {}
vm_not_to_create = {}
nodes = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}

for vm in asl_vms:
  if check_language(vm['name']) == True and check_os_version(vm['distribution']['description']) == True:
    new_vm_name = get_next_hostname(vm['name'])
    vm_res = {'os:' : vm['distribution']['description'],'memory:' : vm['memory'],'cpu:' : vm['cpu'],'cpuNumber:' : vm['cpuNumber'],'disk:' : vm['disk']}
    vm_to_create[new_vm_name] = vm_res  
    ready_for_nodes[nodes] = vm_to_create[new_vm_name]

print(json.dumps(ready_nodes))
```

Вот как на выходе я хочу, чтобы это выглядело в json файле:
Массив, вложенный в массив. Каждый под своим индексом 1.2.3 и тд

```
{
  "1": {
 {
  "aff-java-7.node.eu.consul": {
    "os:": "Debian 10.1 x64",
    "memory:": 1536,
    "cpu:": 2,
    "cpuNumber:": 2,
    "disk:": 8192
  },
  "tgbot-go-7.node.eu.consul": {
    "os:": "Debian 10.1 x64",
    "memory:": 2048,
    "cpu:": 4,
    "cpuNumber:": 4,
    "disk:": 8192
  }
  "2": {
  {
   "aff-java-9.node.eu.consul": {"
     и так далее ресурсы, снова машины уже под индексом 3 и тд и тд
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А как понять, к какой `node` будет относиться `vm_to_create[new_vm_name]`?

Если `node=vm_to_create[new_vm_name]`, т.е. одна `node` содержит только одну `VM`, то самое простое - это использовать `enumerate`:

```
#!/bin/python3

asl_vms = [
    {
        "name": "aff-java-7.node.eu.consul",
        "distribution": {
            "description": "Debian 10.1 x64",
        },
        "memory": 1536,
        "cpu": 2,
        "cpuNumber": 2,
        "disk": 8192
    },
    {
        "name": "tgbot-go-7.node.eu.consul",
        "distribution": {
            "description": "Debian 10.1 x64",
        },
        "description": "10.1 x64",
        "memory": 2048,
        "cpu": 4,
        "cpuNumber": 4,
        "disk": 8192
    },
]

ready_for_nodes = {}

for index, vm in enumerate(asl_vms):
    new_vm_name = vm['name']
    vm_res = {'os:' : vm['distribution']['description'],'memory:' : vm['memory'],'cpu:' : vm['cpu'],'cpuNumber:' : vm['cpuNumber'],'disk:' : vm['disk']}
    ready_for_nodes[index] = {new_vm_name: vm_res}

print(ready_for_nodes)
```

Вывод:

```
{
  0:
    {
      'aff-java-7.node.eu.consul':
      {
        'os:': 'Debian 10.1 x64',
        'memory:': 1536, 
        'cpu:': 2, 
        'cpuNumber:': 2, 
        'disk:': 8192
      }
  },
  1: 
  {
    'tgbot-go-7.node.eu.consul': 
    {
      'os:': 'Debian 10.1 x64',
      'memory:': 2048, 
      'cpu:': 4, 
      'cpuNumber:': 4, 
      'disk:': 8192
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: нет, в целом там несколько имен aff, несколько tgbot, несколько welc. И задача распределить по  `node` как угодно, но если на 1 `node` записали aff, то следующий aff там быть не должно. это надо счетчик какой-то прикрутить... ноя. пока не придумал какой